# AngularJS: Access selected Tab Controller

Tags: angularjs

```
@Html.Partial("CommonHeaderTemplate")
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-include="'HeaderTemplate.html'">
</div>
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab>
        <uib-tab-heading>
            Raw Materials
        </uib-tab-heading>
        <div ng-controller="Controller1">
            //view1
        </div>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab>
        <uib-tab-heading>
            Raw Materials
        </uib-tab-heading>
        <div ng-controller="Controller2">
            //view2
        </div>
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>`
```

My Common header contains a run button.

Both controllers contain the same function `getData()`.

If tab 1 is selected and I click on the run button, the 1st controller's function `getData()` should be called.

If tab 2 is selected and I click on the run button, the 2nd controller's function `getData()` should be called.

Comment: ok. so what did you tried so far

Comment: This will be *quite complex* to code with your current HTML layout.  Unfortunately, the number of ways there are to solve this problem makes this question too broad.  You should try to refine your question a bit, and show what you have tried so far, and the challenges you are having with your current attempts.  see [ask].